# How do you page down in ESXTOP?

Tags: vmware-esx

Call me a ESXtop noob, but how do i see all results in esxtop? Im trying to view DAVG on my iscsi volumes, but can't scroll/page down to view all of them.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to scroll down, are you on the console or in via SSH? What I normally do is ssh in and expand my terminal window to the fulls screen. I can normally see ~ 70 lines this way. If you are just interesting in the VMs then you can type shift+v to show just vm's and not any of hte service console information which will get you a bit more room. If you still cannot see all the information you need, you can run esxtop in [batch mode](http://pubs.vmware.com/vi301/resmgmt/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=resmgmt&file=vc_esxtop.14.10.html) which will give you a csv file to look at.